# Is 32-bit word size limits the virtual space to 4 gigabytes?

Tags: bit

I understand 32-bit word size allows us to $2^{32}$ different numbers. But, why is this number called 4 gigabytes?
4 gigabytes = 4 x 2^30 bytes = 2^32 bytes = 2^35 bits (1 byte = 8 bits)
Is the equation above wrong?? Or the meaning of "bytes" is different?

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit word size allows us to have 2^32 different *addresses*, and each address points to a byte, not to a bit.

(In pretty much every modern architecture, individual bits are not addressable.)

Therefore we get 2^32 bytes = 4 * 2^30 bytes = 4 gigabytes of addressable space.